# How to combine Drawerlayout with BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-jetpack, drawerlayout, android-jetpack-navigation

Build successfully, but the navigation controller doesn't work. When I click on the bottom navigation item, the corresponding fragment will not cover the host fragment.

`MainActivity`

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    private var isInitial = true
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        initView()
    }

    private fun initView(){
        navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_main)
        binding.bottomNavMain.setupWithNavController(navController)
        binding.leftNavMain.setupWithNavController(navController)
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.dish_Fragment, R.id.cart_Fragment, R.id.home_Fragment, R.id.order_Fragment, R.id.friend_Fragment), binding.drawerLayoutMain)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) ||
                super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return findNavController(R.id.nav_host_main).navigateUp(appBarConfiguration)
    }
}
```

`Main xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/container_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/nav_host_main"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/left_nav_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

`Navigation xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.ui.home.MHomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.ui.slideshow.SlideshowFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_slideshow"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_slideshow" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dish_Fragment"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.fragment.DishFragment"
        android:label="dish_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/dish_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/cart_Fragment"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.fragment.CartFragment"
        android:label="cart_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/cart_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home_Fragment"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.fragment.HomeFragment"
        android:label="home_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/home_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/order_Fragment"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.fragment.OrderFragment"
        android:label="order_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/order_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/friend_Fragment"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.fragment.FriendFragment"
        android:label="friend_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/friend_fragment" />

</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

When integrating the Jetpack Navigation, we need to keep the id of destination fragments the same as menu.xml

```kotlin
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.dishFragment, R.id.cartFragment, R.id.homeFragment, R.id.orderFragment, R.id.friendFragment), binding.drawerLayoutMain)
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/dishFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_local_cafe_24"
        android:title="@string/nav_text_one"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cartFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"
        android:title="@string/nav_text_two"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
        android:title="@string/nav_text_three"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/orderFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_assignment_24"
        android:title="@string/nav_text_four"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/friendFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_group_24"
        android:title="@string/nav_text_five"/>
</menu>
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.ui.home.MHomeFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.ui.gallery.GalleryFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_gallery"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_gallery" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.ui.slideshow.SlideshowFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_slideshow"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_slideshow" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dishFragment"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.fragment.DishFragment"
        android:label="dish_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/dish_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/cartFragment"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.fragment.CartFragment"
        android:label="cart_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/cart_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.fragment.HomeFragment"
        android:label="home_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/home_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/orderFragment"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.fragment.OrderFragment"
        android:label="order_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/order_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/friendFragment"
        android:name="com.example.shereats.view.fragment.FriendFragment"
        android:label="friend_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/friend_fragment" />

</navigation>
```